AvalonDock: Auto-Hide Button Hides All Panes in a Group Instead of One
I'm using AvalonDock in a WPF application to create a dockable layout. My layout includes multiple panes in both the left and right panels, and I've set the CanAutoHide property to True for each pane. However, I'm encountering an issue where clicking the auto-hide button on any pane within a LayoutAnchorablePaneGroup causes all the panes in that group to auto-hide together, instead of just the selected one.
Here's a simplified version of my XAML code:
<dock:DockingManager Grid.Row="0">
    <dock:DockingManager.Theme>
        <dock:Vs2013LightTheme/>
    </dock:DockingManager.Theme>

    <dock:LayoutRoot>
        <dock:LayoutPanel Orientation="Vertical">

            <!-- Main Content Area with Top Tabs -->
            <dock:LayoutPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                <!-- Left Panel -->
                <dock:LayoutAnchorablePaneGroup DockWidth="200">
                    <dock:LayoutAnchorablePane>
                        <dock:LayoutAnchorable Title="Left Panel 1" CanClose="False" CanAutoHide="True">
                            <TextBlock Text="Hello"/>
                        </dock:LayoutAnchorable>
                        <dock:LayoutAnchorable Title="Left Panel 2" CanClose="False" CanAutoHide="True">
                            <TextBlock Text="Hello World"/>
                        </dock:LayoutAnchorable>
                        <dock:LayoutAnchorable Title="Left Panel 3" CanClose="False" CanAutoHide="True">
                        </dock:LayoutAnchorable>
                    </dock:LayoutAnchorablePane>
                </dock:LayoutAnchorablePaneGroup>

                <!-- Main Document Area -->
                <dock:LayoutDocumentPane>
                    <dock:LayoutDocument Title="Main Tab 1">
                        <TextBlock Text="Main tab1 content"/>
                    </dock:LayoutDocument>
                    <dock:LayoutDocument Title="Main Tab 2">
                        <TextBlock Text="Content of Main Tab 2" />
                    </dock:LayoutDocument>
                    <dock:LayoutDocument Title="Main Tab 3">
                        <TextBlock Text="Content of Main Tab 3" />
                    </dock:LayoutDocument>
                </dock:LayoutDocumentPane>

                <!-- Right Panel -->
                <dock:LayoutAnchorablePaneGroup DockWidth="200">
                    <dock:LayoutAnchorablePane>
                        <dock:LayoutAnchorable Title="Right Bottom Tab 1" CanClose="False" CanAutoHide="True">
                            <TextBlock Text="Content of Right Bottom Tab 1" />
                        </dock:LayoutAnchorable>
                        <dock:LayoutAnchorable Title="Right Bottom Tab 2" CanClose="False" CanAutoHide="True">
                            <TextBlock Text="Content of Right Bottom Tab 2" />
                        </dock:LayoutAnchorable>
                        <dock:LayoutAnchorable Title="Right Bottom Tab 3" CanClose="False" CanAutoHide="True">
                            <TextBlock Text="Content of Right Bottom Tab 3" />
                        </dock:LayoutAnchorable>
                    </dock:LayoutAnchorablePane>
                </dock:LayoutAnchorablePaneGroup>
            </dock:LayoutPanel>

            <!-- Bottom Panel with Full Width -->
            <dock:LayoutAnchorablePaneGroup Orientation="Horizontal" DockHeight="200">
                <dock:LayoutAnchorablePane>
                    <dock:LayoutAnchorable Title="Bottom Tab 1" CanClose="False" CanAutoHide="True">
                        <TextBlock Text="Content of Bottom Tab 1" />
                    </dock:LayoutAnchorable>
                    <dock:LayoutAnchorable Title="Bottom Tab 2" CanClose="False" CanAutoHide="True">
                        <TextBlock Text="Content of Bottom Tab 2" />
                    </dock:LayoutAnchorable>
                    <dock:LayoutAnchorable Title="Bottom Tab 3" CanClose="False" CanAutoHide="True">
                        <TextBlock Text="Content of Bottom Tab 3" />
                    </dock:LayoutAnchorable>
                </dock:LayoutAnchorablePane>
            </dock:LayoutAnchorablePaneGroup>

        </dock:LayoutPanel>
    </dock:LayoutRoot>
</dock:DockingManager>

The problem arises when I try to auto-hide one of the panes in either the left or right groups. Instead of hiding just the selected pane, all panes in the group hide together. This behavior occurs for both the left and right pane groups.
Is there a way to modify the configuration so that only the clicked pane auto-hides instead of the entire group? Any help would be appreciated!
